# AVX2 barycentric interpolation of a vertex component

Tags: c++, optimization, interpolation, simd, avx2

I'm just starting out on the path of using simd intrinsics. My profiler has shown that a significant amount of time is being spent on vertex interpolation. I am targeting AVX2 and am trying to find an optimization for the following - given that I have 3 vector2s that need interpolation I imagine I should be able to load them into a single __m256 and do the multiply and add efficiently. Here is the code I am trying to convert - is it worth doing it as a 256bit operation? The vectors are unaligned.

```
Vector2 Interpolate( Vector3 uvw, Vector2 v0, Vector2 v1, Vector2 v2 )
{
   Vector2 out;
   out = v0 * uvw.x;
   out += v1 * uvw.y;
   out += v2 * uvw.z;

   return out;
}

struct Vector2 { float x; float y; } ;
struct Vector3 { float x; float y; float z; } ;
```

My question is this - how do I load three unaligned vector2 into the single 256bit register so I can do the multiply and add?

I am using VS2013.

Comment: Too much annoying data movement would be necessary. If you passed the vertexes (all those that need interpolating, not just 3) and the scaling factors as arrays you could actually write reasonable code

Comment: @harold How many elements at a time would make it worth while? 16 sets? 256 sets?

Comment: How about `struct Vector2_block { float8 x; float8 y; } ;` and `struct Vector3_block { float8 x; float8 y; float8 z; } ;` and then you operate on 8 vertices at once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was bored so I wrote it, not tested (but compiled, both Clang and GCC make reasonable code from this)

```
void interpolateAll(int n, float* scales, float* vin, float* vout)
{
  // preconditions:
  // (n & 7 == 0) (not really, but vout must be padded)
  // scales & 31 == 0
  // vin & 31 == 0
  // vout & 31 == 0

  // vin format:
  // float v0x[8]
  // float v0y[8]
  // float v1x[8]
  // float v1y[8]
  // float v2x[8]
  // float v2y[8]
  // scales format:
  // float scale0[8]
  // float scale1[8]
  // float scale2[8]
  // vout format:
  // float vx[8]
  // float vy[8]

  for (int i = 0; i < n; i += 8) {
    __m256 scale_0 = _mm256_load_ps(scales + i * 3);
    __m256 scale_1 = _mm256_load_ps(scales + i * 3 + 8);
    __m256 scale_2 = _mm256_load_ps(scales + i * 3 + 16);
    __m256 v0x = _mm256_load_ps(vin + i * 6);
    __m256 v0y = _mm256_load_ps(vin + i * 6 + 8);
    __m256 v1x = _mm256_load_ps(vin + i * 6 + 16);
    __m256 v1y = _mm256_load_ps(vin + i * 6 + 24);
    __m256 v2x = _mm256_load_ps(vin + i * 6 + 32);
    __m256 v2y = _mm256_load_ps(vin + i * 6 + 40);
    __m256 x = _mm256_mul_ps(scale_0, v0x);
    __m256 y = _mm256_mul_ps(scale_0, v0y);
    x = _mm256_fmadd_ps(scale_1, v1x, x);
    y = _mm256_fmadd_ps(scale_1, v1y, y);
    x = _mm256_fmadd_ps(scale_2, v2x, x);
    y = _mm256_fmadd_ps(scale_2, v2y, y);
    _mm256_store_ps(vout + i * 2, x);
    _mm256_store_ps(vout + i * 2 + 8, y);
  }
}
```

Uses Z boson's format, if I understood him correctly. In any case it's a nice format, from a SIMD perspective. Slightly inconvenient from a C++ perspective.

The FMAs do serialize the multiplies unnecessarily but that shouldn't matter since it's not part of a loop-carried dependency.

The predicted throughput of this (assuming a small enough array) is 2 iterations per 9 cycles, bottlenecked by the loads. In practice probably slightly worse, there was some talk about simple stores stealing p2 or p3 occasionally, that sort of thing, I'm not really sure. Anyway, that's enough time for 18 "FMAs" but there are only 12 (8 and 4 mulps), so it may be useful to move some extra computation in here if there is any.

Comment: Thank you - I will give it a try when I can reconfigure the source data into streams. Right now the raytracer is really setup on a 'per ray' result.

Comment: This is generally what I ended up doing - I rewrote the code to generate eight rays at once and then made everything else match that. It works for the most part but there are some expensive operations where I take a collection of hit objects with disperate data and have to shuffle it around, but that's for another question. Thanks again.